# Problems simulating purchase with StoreKit 2

Tags: swift, macos, storekit, swift5

I'm trying to test my IAPs for my macOS app with the new StoreKit 2 API.

I have created a `.storekit` file and have assigned it in my scheme under Run > Options > StoreKit Configuration.

Retrieving the test products works without problems:

```swift
let identifiers = Set(["myProductId"])
let products = try await Product.products(for: identifiers)
```

But when I want to simulate a purchase nothing happens. It's stuck and never prints the result.

```swift
func purchase(product: Product) async throws {
    print("Purchasing \(product.id) ...")
    let result = try await product.purchase()
    print(result)
}
```

I'm currently on macOS Monterey Beta 8 and Xcode 13 beta 5.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.
 But, the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10114) and [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_a_store_in_your_app_using_the_storekit_api) works well. Also, I've found that [deleting transactions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting-up-storekit-testing-in-xcode) can help too. Also, make sure you are using the sandbox account and not your real account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure the Sandbox is configured with Outgoing Connections (Client) enabled:

[image: Sandbox configuration]

Comment: Is this different from what happened with the older StoreKit APIs?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't use StoreKit before.